# Navbar with two rows with RSCSS

Tags: css, rscss

I' trying to use [RSCSS](https://github.com/rstacruz/rscss) on my project.

I've a navbar with two rows and each row has columns.

Is this correct or should I use something different?

```
.top-navbar
  .subnavbar-one
    .column
    .column
  .subnavbar-two
    .column
    .column
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-replying because I think I've found the solution.

I should use a structure like this:

```
.top-navbar
  .subnavbar.-one
    .column
    .column
  .subnavbar.-two
    .column
    .column
```

Where `-one` and `-two` are two modifiers of the `subnavbar` element.

Comment: rscss author here, yes that makes sense :)